# using python, how do we delete the auth_user column from the proxy log file?

Tags: python, text, delimiter

I have hundreds of proxy log files in one folder and want delete the `auth_user` column from all the log files and output them to another folder.

The `auth_user` column is enclosed by double quotes. The biggest problem is I can not use space characters as the text delimiter, because some log files have no space between `timestamp` and `auth_user`. I tried to use double quote as the text delimiter, but this leads to some weird results, since sometimes there is nothing between the pairs of  double quotes.

What I have so far:

```
for src_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.log')):
    base = os.path.basename(src_name)
    dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir,base)
    with open(src_name, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(dest_name, 'w') as outfile:
             reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='"')
             writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='"')
             for row in reader:
                 row[1] = ''
                 writer.writerow(row)
```

The log file is as follows (`time_stamp` `"auth_user"` `src_ip`):

```
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]"cn=john smith,ou=central,ou=microsoft,o=com" 192.168.2.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"jsmith" 192.168.4.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"" 192.168.15.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"" 192.168.4.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"jkenndy" 192.168.14.5
```

I would like to change it into this (`time_stamp` `src_ip`):

```
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300] 192.168.2.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.4.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.15.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.4.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.14.5
```

Comment: Does the `auth_user` line start without a time stamp? What about the empty quotes in the line after `auth_user`? Do you want to have the data beginning at the `username` line only? If those two lines are at the beginning of the file you can ignore them when reading the file by starting at line three.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. **please don't write questions in all bold as it feels like you're shouting at us.** :)

Comment: #time_stamp "auth_user"          <----- Correction for first line

Comment: Try my answer below. I think it does what you need.

Comment: A typical proxy log has 15 coulmns and stevieb's solution works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each file has the structure:

```
#[some timestamp here]"auth_user"
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]""
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]"username"
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]"machine$"
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]"cn=john smith,ou=central,ou=microsoft,o=com"
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"jsmith"
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]""
#[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]""
```

Assuming that the first two lines need to be skipped:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

with open('file.log') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        # line_number starts at zero, skip both lines at beginning of file
        if line_number > 1:
            # process file here, replace print statement with appropriate code
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSV, can you just open the file normally, and use a regex? The following will remove the auth_user column regardless of whether there's a space after the timestamp, or whether there is anything inside the quotes or not:

```
import re

with open('in.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\d{4}])|(?<=#time_stamp))\s*".*?"', '', line)
        print(line)
```

Input:

```
#time_stamp "auth_user" src_ip 
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300]"cn=johnsmith,ou=central,ou=microsoft,o=com" 192.168.2.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"jsmith" 192.168.4.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"" 192.168.15.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"" 192.168.4.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400]"jkenndy" 192.168.14.5
```

Output:

```
#time_stamp src_ip
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:00 -0300] 192.168.2.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.4.5
[21/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.15.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.4.5
[22/Apr/2013:00:00:01 -0400] 192.168.14.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `re` regular expressions module to break each line of the log file into three groups, and then just write the first and third group to the output file:

```
import glob
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''(\[.+\])(".*")( .+)''')

for src_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.log')):
    base = os.path.basename(src_name)
    dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, base)
    with open(src_name, 'rt') as infile, open(dest_name, 'wt') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            groups = pattern.search(line).groups()
            outfile.write(groups[0]+groups[2]+'\n')
```